# 6-pin SMD identification on BMS smart controller

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, bms

Can anyone help me identify the component in the attached picture? I've never seen a similar package.

[image]

Comment: Might be HSOP-6J package https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/package/FH006-A.pdf

Comment: Darn... That dot is covering up the first two numbers/letters of that part number. Curses to the manufacturer for their obfuscation!

Comment: Great! It could be a regulator from ablic! I was reading 1428 but probably the last character is B. In this case it could be S-1142B33I

Answer (score 2):

Yes you probably right, the only findable designation with 142B and 33I in the second line is [S-1142B33I](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/voltage_regulator/S1142A_B_E.pdf) prefix (HSOP-6J package from ABLIC). The marking clearly corresponds.

Nothing found with 1428.

[Picture link (Aliexpress)](https://es.aliexpress.com/i/32893528765.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2esp)

[image]